# VBA - Count Rows then in Column C then fill Columns A, B and P with Equations

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 columns.  Column C "Account" and column D "Person" are my data set.

I want to use VBA to look at how many rows of data I have and then fill that number of rows in 1) Column E "Concatenate" with a concatenate of "Account" and "Employee" fill that number of rows in 2) columns A and B with an INDEX-MATCH equation I have.

..I tried to draw out my columns below but it isn't formatting in the way I'd like it to be... sorry

```
Owner | Comment | Account | Employee | Concatenate
Jay   | Done    | JSMA1   | Sally    | JSMA1 Sally
Will  | Not Done| KLLM4   | Jack     | KLLM4 Jack
Ken   | Done    | BM3R1   | Sam      | BM3R1 Sam
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What code do you have so far? You could use the `CurrentRegion` method of the `Range` object to get a reference to the block of data and then use the `Rows` property to get the number of rows. For example,  `numRows = Workbook("name_of_book.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet_name").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub fillRanges()

    Dim ur As Range, hdr As Range, conCol As Variant, lRow As Long
    Dim ownCol As Variant, comCol As Variant
    Dim actCol As Variant, empCol As Variant

    Set ur = Sheet1.UsedRange   ' minimal range
    Set hdr = ur.Rows(1)        ' header row
    lRow = ur.Rows.Count        ' last row

    With Application
        ownCol = .Match("Owner", hdr, 0)
        comCol = .Match("Comment", hdr, 0)
        actCol = .Match("Account", hdr, 0)
        empCol = .Match("Employee", hdr, 0)
        conCol = .Match("Concatenate", hdr, 0)
    End With

    If Not IsError(ownCol) And _
        Not IsError(comCol) And _
        Not IsError(actCol) And _
        Not IsError(empCol) And _
        Not IsError(conCol) _
    Then
        With ur
            .Range(.Cells(2, ownCol), .Cells(lRow, ownCol)) = "INDEX-MATCH equation 1"
            .Range(.Cells(2, comCol), .Cells(lRow, comCol)) = "INDEX-MATCH equation 2"
            .Range(.Cells(2, conCol), .Cells(lRow, conCol)).Formula = _
                "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()," & actCol & ")) & "" "" & " & _
                " INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), " & empCol & "))"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect Paul, thank you.  I'm not familiar with some of the syntax used such as IsError, Indirect(address(row()).  I'm trying to learn them now.

Comment: I'm glad it helps. IsError is a VBA function (there is and Excel equivalent for it) and it returns True for these types of errors: "#DIV/0!", "#N/A", "#NAME?", "#NULL", "#NUM!", "#REF", "#VALUE!"

Comment: Normally I'd avoid using "INDIRECT" because it's volatile - it forces recalculations and updates with every change. It works like this: if cell A1 has the value "C3", then =INDIRECT(A1) will return the value in cell C3. If you have a lot of data (thousands of rows or more) we should probably use something else to concatenate the fields